# Activating Windows 7 generates error code 0xc004F061

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I upgrade a corrupted OEM copy of Windows Vista to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/237863/can-i-upgrade-a-corrupted-oem-copy-of-windows-vista-to-windows-7)

I got a new SSD and wanted to start over with Windows 7 on that disk. I did a clean install (my mistake) on the SSD and just went passed the activation part (left the key blank). Now that I have my system all setup, configured, files pulled back from backup, and ready to go, I'd like to activate Windows 7. However, I now get this error:

> The following failure occurred while
>   trying to use the product key:
>
> Code:
>
> 0xC004F061
>
> Description:
>
> The Software Licensing Service
>   determined that this specified product
>   key can only be used for upgrading,
>   not for clean installations.

Do I *really* need to wipe my system again, install Windows Vista, and then do the Windows 7 upgrade in order to use my upgrade key? Is there some kind of work around?

Answer (score 2):

Legally, the answer is yes. Sorry :(

You can try ringing the toll free Microsoft number and begging, they may let you off!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to contact the Microsoft Activation Center (you can get the phone number local to you via the [Manual/Telephone Activation part of the Activation Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929)).

Activation support calls are free, and they'll either get you going with it as-is, or confirm if you need to reinstall and pick 'Upgrade'.

Answer (score 1):

I know this trick worked when Windows 7 came out but have not tried it in a while, however it still may be worth a shot. Install the full version without a key, then reinstall using the upgrade option on top of the initial version, enter your upgrade key. My first copy of 7 was just an upgrade so I had to do this a few times... I know it worked last time I tried about a year ago since then I got a regular windows 7 copy.